# Repeating calculation for multiple rows on input data on a different worksheet

Tags: excel

I have built a very extensive calculation in a workbook which requires multiple inputs (3) and returns multiple outputs (2).

I have also created a worksheet with time-stamped inputs for the calculation (>17500 rows on input data) and am trying to figure out a way to calculate the two output results for each row of data.

Example of input data:

```
Timestamp             FT-210          TT-204          PT-202
01/10/2013 7:00:00  118.2394581     38.5697158      2684.327958
01/10/2013 7:00:05  117.8374941000  39.5360098000   2685.8244490000
01/10/2013 7:00:10  119.4888971000  40.0025628000   2683.9299580000
01/10/2013 7:00:15  122.0910511000  39.9404128000   2680.0473750000
01/10/2013 7:00:20  125.0456801000  40.6752238000   2676.6639220000
```

I would like to be able to run the calculations for each line of inputs, and return the two outputs to the same worksheet.

Comment: You might want to show us your "very extensive calculation".

Comment: What are inputs and what are outputs?