# Excel VBA: Repeating calculation for multiple rows on input data on a different worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with 3 worksheets (Raw Data, Inputs, and Results).

I want to take the contents of B2, T2, U2, and AM2 on Raw Data and put it into B2, B10, B31, and C15 on Inputs respectively.

Doing this changes the contents of cells C14 and C15 on Results, which I then want to put into EC2 and ED2 on Raw Data.

Then I want the same thing to happen to B3, T3, U3, and AM3 etc - the next row of information on Raw Data basically, and then the next row after that, and so on for a lot of rows.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help and point me in the right direction!

The closest post I found on here from someone else (link below) wasn't answered - so if you need any more information or clarification on what I am trying to achieve, please let me know!

[Repeating calculation for multiple rows on input data on a different worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19796613/repeating-calculation-for-multiple-rows-on-input-data-on-a-different-worksheet)

Thank you!

Mike

Comment: There's a reason there are no answers to your link. You need to show some own effort. Just asking for complete code won't do. Try it for yourself (Start with recording a macro, may use google...) and if you can present us some code and point out exactly what **problem** you encountered, we will be glad to help.

Comment: I quite appreciate your point which is why I ask for pointing in the right direction - something to google and work with on my own.  Once I have something written down in VBA I suspect I may be back for help on where I went wrong, but that is for another time.  I'm not quite so cheeky as to ask someone to do my work for me entirely!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would recommend looking into FOR loops since you are trying to repeat a procedure throughout a range. Here is Microsoft's [introduction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx) to them.

Inside the loop you are going to assign values to cells on one sheet based on values of cells on another. I will leave it up to you to do some research on that topic.

You will also want to look into using a variable inside your cell references so that they change as your loop progresses through the workbook.

Comment: Thank you for the link and suggested start point - exactly what I was after - much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to come up with the below which is along the right lines I think, just got to insert some variable references now.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Raw Data")
    Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Inputs")
    Set ws3 = wb.Worksheets("Results")
    Set rng = ws1.Range("A2:ED193")
        For Each row In rng.Rows
            ws1.Range("B").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("B2")
            ws1.Range("T").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("B10")
            ws1.Range("U").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("B31")
            ws1.Range("AM").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("C15")
            ws3.Range("C14").Copy Destination:=ws1.Range("EC")
            ws3.Range("C15").Copy Destination:=ws1.Range("ED")
        Next row
End Sub
```